# Find bounded integers $x, y$ minimizing $| t - x * y |$

Tags: integer-programming

How do I find the integers $x$ and $y$ minimizing $| t - x \cdot y |$ with $1 \leq x < N$ and $1 \leq y < M$ ?

Background: A clock signal is divided by two hardware prescalers (with a limited number of bits), how do I produce an output frequency that is as close as possible to the desired frequency ?

Comment: Do you search theoretical or practical solutions?  How to deal with multiple solutions, e.g. for $t=10007, x<512, y<512$ you have 6 pairs with minimum distance 1:
`(24,417), (36,278), (72,139), (139,72), (278,36), (417,24)` i.e. **the** solution maybe does no exist, there is no solution with distance $0$ because t is prime. I have used a simple linear search for $x=\lfloor t / (y_{max}+1\rfloor.. x_{max}$

Comment: I'm looking for a practical solution faster than O(N) or O(M). I am aware that there may be multiple solutions, finding one of them is enough.

Comment: So `N` and `M` are necessarily powers of 2?  How big is `t`?  Does it factor nicely?